# Can the "Go get it" for the Editor badge be linked to a Question page?

Tags: feature-request, badges, profile-page

On the profile page, when I choose Editor as the next badge I'm tracking, it gives me the option to "Go get it." Clicking on that leads me to [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:mine+score:0), which is a search page. I don't know how to search for questions that might need editing!

Wouldn't it make more sense for it to link to one of the Question pages, like [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions), giving me the option to look through the questions until I find something to edit?